# Unity Camera doesnt show the whole Gamescreen (Canvas) on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera

I finished my Game and want to upload it to the Google Play Store soon.
But before I need to fix the following "Bug" where I need your help!

In Unity Editor the Game works correctly

[image: Unity Gamewindow (See the Top UI)]

But now if I play the Game on my Samsung Galaxy S8 it seems like this 
(Ignore the top and bottom image, its because I dont play in Fullscreen)

[image: Gamescreen Android]

As you can see there is missing a bit from the left and right screen.

How can I fix this? Im using an Orthographic Camera and in Canvas I use the "World Space" Render Mode to render all.

[image: My Gamescreen Canvas]

In the Playersettings I use the max Aspect Ratio from 16.9

[image: Player Settings]

Answer (score 1):

In your last photo Supported Aspect Ratio's property Up To is 16.9 but Galaxy S8's ratio is 18.5:9 . Change property Up To and I thing your bug will be solved.

[Here is Photo with information about your phone's screen's ratio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKfdD.png)

Comment: Cant type ":" in the "Aspect Ratio Up To" Field. Do you have any other idea to deal with that Problem?

Comment: @Gagik gave good direction.. I just had the same issue.. Write in the `Up To` 2.1 and it should work, at least in my case.

Comment: If your problem still exist you can see this article, guy have same problem 
https://forum.unity.com/threads/dealing-with-samsung-s8-insane-aspect-ratio-how-to-letter-box-an-app.512417/